# How to change this Ruby on Rails code to Laravel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, laravel

Recently I have started learning Ruby on Rails. I am currently converting an existing ruby on rails project to Laravel. But as I am new in Ruby on Rails I do not understand some parts of the existing part.

In the existing Ruby on rails project application_controller.rb there is a function. I do not understand the meaning of the function. Would anyone please explain the meaning of the code?

application_controller.rb

```
 def new_year_holidays?
    t = Time.now

    @notification = t >= Rails.application.config.new_year_holidays_start_at &&
                    t <= Rails.application.config.new_year_holidays_finish_at
    start_date = Rails.application.config.new_year_holidays_start_at 
    end_date   = Rails.application.config.new_year_holidays_finish_at
    @new_year_holidays_start_at = start_date.strftime("%Y年%m月%d日(#{%w(日 月 火 水 木 金 土)[start_date.wday]})")
    @new_year_holidays_finish_at = end_date.strftime("%Y年%m月%d日(#{%w(日 月 火 水 木 金 土)[end_date.wday]})")
  end
```

in the view they have used this variable notification

```
 <% if @notification %>
  <p style="border: 1px solid #dab682; background: #fef4d0; text-align: center; width:98%; margin: 0 auto 20px; padding: 10px; color:#a9692b; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.7;">  
    <%= @new_year_holidays_start_at  %>より<%= @new_year_holidays_finish_at %>までの年末年始の間、<br>
    お見積もりや資料の発送・配送に通常よりお時間を頂く可能性がございます。ご了承ください。</div>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

All I know new_year_holidays is a function here.but I don't know why there is a question mark. And I know notification and `new_year_holidays_start_at` and `@new_year_holidays_finish_at variable here`. In the controller they have use the `application_controller.rb`

```
Kakaku::PackageEstimatesController < ApplicationControllerhere
```

I am beginner in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common practice in ruby to use question mark in the name of a method, which returns boolean (true/false)
Your method just check, if current time is inside holidays. I refactored it a bit

```
def new_year_holidays?
  t = Time.now # it is better to use Time.current, it works with timezones

  # it is two dates from configuration file, you can redefine them anytime
  start_date = Rails.application.config.new_year_holidays_start_at 
  end_date   = Rails.application.config.new_year_holidays_finish_at 

  # if current time is between start and end dates from config, @notification == true, otherwise - false
  @notification = t >= start_date && t <= end_date

  @new_year_holidays_start_at = start_date.strftime("%Y年%m月%d日(#{%w(日 月 火 水 木 金 土)[start_date.wday]})")
  @new_year_holidays_finish_at = end_date.strftime("%Y年%m月%d日(#{%w(日 月 火 水 木 金 土)[end_date.wday]})")
end
```

All @ variables are available inside views, so if @notification is `true` the user will see block with holidays dates

Comment: I want to use this notification variable in laravel. How can I use this in laravel ? this function

Comment: @sharna, sorry, but I have no knowledge about laravel. You question was: 'Can anyone please explain me the meaning of the code? '. I explained. If you need somebody to help you with a new laravel code, please add `laravel` tag and edit your question

Answer (score 0):

The question mark in `new_year_holidays?` indicates that the method returns a boolean value, like `true` or `false`. The code `new_year_holidays?` seems to determine if current day is a new year holiday or not.

Answer (score 0):

Question mark is valid at the end of a method's name in Ruby world.

This is simply a convention which means that it would return a boolean value. In other languages' convention, it might would be `is_new_year_holidays`, `isNewYearHolidays` or `IsNewYearHolidays`

Ruby implicitly returns the value of last evaluated expression. So in `new_year_holidays?` method, it returns the value of
`@new_year_holidays_finish_at`and it doesn’t seem to be returning a boolean value. I would say it is a bad method name.